# export data as excel file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can easily export data as excel file with a simple code but I get a problem when I need to call the export.php by j query code. Data is not downloaded as export.php file. The code is :

```
<?php
include '../../config.php';
function cleanData(&$str)
{
    if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
    if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';
    if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
        $str = "'$str";
    }
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
}

$filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv<span>; charset=UTF-16LE</span>");

$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');

$flag = false;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee") or die('Query failed!');
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    if(!$flag) {
        fputcsv($out, array_keys($row), ',', '"');
        $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    if($row['photo']!='')
    {
        $row['photo']="http://localhost/admin/employee_image/".$row['photo'];
    }
    fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
}
fclose($out);
exit;
```

Is there any way to call this file by jquery?

Comment: You mean by ajax call here?

Comment: ya i mean by ajax call here

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this by Javascript using jQuery or any other library, AJAX calls data in Javascript engine inside the browser.

But you can use HTML5 download attribute:

```
<a href="your_file.xls" download="YourFile.xls">Download Excel</a>
```

And give proper headers in PHP:

```
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.xls"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

EDIT:

Although the above will work, I take my words back as I found this:

http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Made by https://stackoverflow.com/users/455556/john-culviner ,  ask him for help if you need

Cheers!

Comment: where i need to provide php file path?

Comment: i need some pass session value in <a > tag so that data will be fetch can i post data in <a> tag ?

Comment: if you want to post data you will have to make a form, you can send GET parameters by making a query string in the href

Comment: then make a form and post it to your url

Comment: no i need to export data based on ajax call there is any solution for that in php

Comment: Sure, havent u checked the links i gave the jquery plugin does exactly what u want